# How do I "rubberstamp" the bq load event in Google BigQuery?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have the following file structure

```
0916/
  day09/
    part001.file.orc
    ...
  day14/
    part001.file.orc
    ...
0923/
  day09/
    part001.file.orc
    ...
  day10/
    part001.file.orc
    ...
  day15/
    part001.file.orc
    ...
```

This happens because data "ingestion" may be completed a few days after first uploading to storage, resulting in some small part of `day09` still uploaded on `0923`.

I use `bq load ...` to upload from storage to BQ, but I'd like to keep some "signature" or "rubberstamp" of where the data came from, for example, having the schema in orc, but also adding a column with the parent folder, so the schema would be

```
field1
field2
...
source
```

where source would be 0916, 0930 for that particular row. Can this be done somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible as part of `bq load`, unless the column is added to the actual data.

I would switch to a three step process:

1. `bq load` Load the data to a staging table first.
2. `bq query` Run a query from the staging table to the target table adding the extra field. Can be done with an `WRITE_APPEND` query if you are adding to table or partitions.
3. `bq rm` Delete the staging table.

Query to append source example:

```
SELECT 
  *,
  "0923" AS source
FROM staging_table
```